# error de lectura openssl_encrypt y decrypt

Tags: php

Tengo un problema cuando trato de recuperar el valor del id encriptado mediante $_GET.

------ index.php ------

```
    <?php 
    
    $metodo="AES-128-ECB";
    $key = "cualquierclave";
    
    ?>

<a href"single.php?post=<?php echo openssl_encrypt($id,$metodo,$key)">Pasar </a>
```

donde el id es 2

> echo post = "5k/rSTC3+ECkS8RDwka8IA" <-- este es el valor encriptado
> noten que tiene un signo +

----- single.php --------

```
$id = isset($_GET['post']) ? $_GET['post'] : '';

$id = openssl_decrypt($id,$metodo,$key);
```

> echo $id ="5k/rSTC3 ECkS8RDwka8IA" <----- cuando lo recupero y lo
> desencripto el signo + desaparece y me da error.

es decir que esto pasa cuando cualquier id encriptado tiene un signo + al recuperarlo lo desaparece y coloca un espacio.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas imprimir el valor codificado para `URL` y para esto podrías usar [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.urlencode.php)

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php 
$metodo="AES-128-ECB";
$key = "cualquierclave";
$post = urlencode(openssl_encrypt($id, $metodo, $key));
?>

<a href="single.php?post=<?php echo $post; ?>">Pasar </a>
```

Comment: lo coloco así como me dices, y no sale el signo mas ni antes ni después. queda un espacio. 5k/rSTC3 ECkS8RDwka8IA

Comment: @EduardoRamirez, es raro te dejo [esta demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/470d573a96844254fc289a2ded9ace3ef147beee)